# for-loop or create functions to create matrix (or dataframe) and rename columns

Tags: r, for-loop

I was trying to generate several new matrix and rename columns and rows with the same actions but different variable values. Follows are the codes I did in a slow way, I tried to use for-loop and functions to do this but could not find a correct approach.

```
m0 <- 100
N <- 1
CS <- 10.141 
S <- seq (7.72,12.56,0.807)
t <- 15 

per3 <- matrix(nrow = length(S)*N, ncol = t+1)
for (i in 1:dim(per3)[1]) {
  for (j in 1:t+1){
    per3 [,1] <- replicate (n = N, seq (7.72,12.56,0.807))
    per3 [i,j] <- round (abs (rnorm (1, mean = mean(per3[i,1]), sd = 0.2)),digits=3)
  }}
colnames(per3) <- c('physical','t1','t2','t3','t4','t5','t6','t7','t8','t9','t10','t11','t12','t13','t14','t15')
rownames(per3) <- c('S1','S2','S3','CS+','S5','S6')
per3 <- per3 [,-1]

per3_d = matrix(nrow = length(S)*N, ncol = t)
for (i in 1:dim(per3)[1]){
  for (j in 1:t){
    per3_d [i,j] <- abs (per3 [i,j] - 10.141) 
  }
}

g31 <- round (m0 * exp (-0.2 * per3_d),digits = 3)
g32 <- round (m0 * exp (-0.5 * per3_d),digits = 3)
g33 <- round (m0 * exp (-0.9 * per3_d),digits = 3)
g34 <- round (m0 * exp (-1.5 * per3_d),digits = 3)
g35 <- round (m0 * exp (-2 * per3_d),digits = 3)
colnames(g31) <- c('t1','t2','t3','t4','t5','t6','t7','t8','t9','t10','t11','t12','t13','t14','t15')
colnames(g32) <- c('t1','t2','t3','t4','t5','t6','t7','t8','t9','t10','t11','t12','t13','t14','t15')
colnames(g33) <- c('t1','t2','t3','t4','t5','t6','t7','t8','t9','t10','t11','t12','t13','t14','t15')
colnames(g34) <- c('t1','t2','t3','t4','t5','t6','t7','t8','t9','t10','t11','t12','t13','t14','t15')
colnames(g35) <- c('t1','t2','t3','t4','t5','t6','t7','t8','t9','t10','t11','t12','t13','t14','t15')
```

A same problems as follows, I need to make g31,g32,g33,g34,g35 as dataframes, can I use for loop to do this rather than repeat the actions?

```
sub1pd<-as.data.frame (per_d)
sub1p<-as.data.frame(per)
sub1g11 <- as.data.frame(g11)
sub1g12 <- as.data.frame(g12)
sub1g13 <- as.data.frame(g13)
sub1g14 <- as.data.frame(g14)
sub1g15 <- as.data.frame(g15)
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

---

I tried to use the same method you used for per and per_d where I again have same structure but different sd values. However, I am not sure how to do this as I have different steps to generate data for first column and the rest for each per and per_d.

```
sd <- c(0.2, 0.5, 0.9)
names(sd) <- paste("per", seq_along(sd), sep = "") 
res <- lapply(sd, function(x){ 
  per <- matrix(nrow = length(S)*N, ncol = t+1)
  for (i in 1:dim(per)[1]) {
    for (j in 1:t+1){
      per [,1] <- replicate (n = N, seq (7.72,12.56,0.807))
      per [i,j] <- round (abs (rnorm (1, mean = mean(per[i,1]), sd = x)),digits=3)
      colnames(per) <- paste(t, 1:ncol(per), sep = "")
      per <- as.data.frame (per)
    }
    }
}
)
```

[image]

Comment: could you provide `m0` and `per3_d` so we could have a reproducible example? first guess `lapply(c(-0.2, -0.5, -0.9, - 1.5, - 2), function(x){ g <- round (m0 * exp (x * per3_d),digits = 3)...`

Comment: YES, I just edited my question with m0 and per3_d.Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Please verify if your code can be run, not all variables are defined in the example. `S`, `N`, `t`

Comment: really sorry about that, I have now define all the variables in the question

Comment: I guess the part `for (i in 1:dim(per)[1])` should be `for (i in 1:dim(per3)[1])`?

Comment: It is dim(per3). really sorry about this.

Comment: No problem, we were all new contributors at some point. Welcome to SO. If you need clarification for my answer don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you are iterating manually . This is highly inefficient. One way to simplify the code is to iterate using a `for` loop and there is nothing wrong with that in R (I mention this since many people think otherwise) if you know what and why you are doing. But as an R user you should acquaint yourself with the `apply` family of functions especially [`lapply`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/lapply)

```
exps <- c(-0.2, -0.5, -0.9, -1.5, - 2)
names(exps) <- paste("g3", seq_along(exps), sep = "") #name the vactor

res <- lapply(exps, function(x){ #for each x element in the exps vector perform the function
  g <- round(m0 * exp (x * per3_d), digits = 3)
  colnames(g) <- paste("t", 1:ncol(g), sep = "") #avoid typing sequences which can be generated easily
  g <- as.data.frame(g)
  g
}
)
```

This way all the data frames will be in a list which will allow much easier further manipulation.

If you really need the list elements in the environment (I highly doubt you really do):

```
list2env(res, globalenv())
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. May I ask what I should do next to name them as g31,g32,g33... and put them as separate dataframes? I need to unlist it first right?

Comment: Could you explain why you need them as separate data frames? Most likely this is not necessary, but I eddied the answer to show how it can be done.

Comment: Sorry this might be a stupid question. I am a beginner with R. I understand what you did here as to run g31~g35 together with lapply and put them as a list. What I am not sure now is what I should do later when I need to use g31~g35 separately to do further calculations and make plots. With separate data frames it is clear to me how to do following actions.

Comment: `res$g31` you can obtain separate df like this. If you want them in the `env()` use `list2env(res, globalenv())`

Comment: Thank you very much again for your answers. I see what I should do now (I need to put 't' rather than t otherwise column names will become 151,152...)!! Thank you so much for taking your time answering my questions!

Comment: I understand how everything works now! Really appreciate your helps!

Comment: Sorry. Would you mind give me another example which I supposed should be very similar to the apply method you used? It's the per3 and per3_d that I used to calculate g31-g35, for which I have per1-per3 and per1-per3_d separately. I tried myself but not sure how to do as I already used for-loop in each of them. (I specified this at the end of my question)

Comment: just the sd variable is different when you construct  `per1-per3`? if so, just lapply over the sd variable

Comment: may you take a look of where I did it wrong? I lapply over the sd variables but could not run it. I put the codes at the end of my question.

Comment: at the end of the function call you should return the result. After `per <- as.data.frame (per)` add one more line with `per` or `return(per)`. Does it solve the problem?

Comment: Only the first column works, for the rest where depended on different sd (different values for x) it turned to NA. The codes for for-loop are exactly the same as my initial codes, and the initial codes can turn correct values without problems.

Comment: the return code should be outside of the loop: `per <- as.data.frame(per)
    }
  }
  per`. Sorry I thought it was obvious. The last thing in the function should be the value that is returned.

Comment: I got it now, it was really a stupid mistake. Thank you so much for your patience, I do really learn a lot from this.